# Logarithmic scaling / colorbar in Julia using PyPlot (matplotlib)

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I am using Julia 0.5 and the latest version of PyPlot.
I am printing an 2D-Array using `plot.pcolor`and it works pretty good. But now I have data that needs a logarithmic scaling. I searched on the web and what I found was an example using

`plt.pcolor(X, Y, Z1, norm=LogNorm(vmin=Z1.min(), vmax=Z1.max()), cmap='PuBu_r')`

But since `LogNorm` seems to be a python function ist doesn't work in Julia. Does anyone have an idea what I can hand over to `norm=`to get a logarithmic scaling?

An example would be:

```
using PyPlot
A = rand(20,20)
figure()
PyPlot.pcolor(A, cmap="PuBu_r")
colorbar()
```

Comment: If this is not implemented in julia's pyplot, you have to implement it yourself. It's a fairly easy function to port. [See here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/84d979b9b55d5165630aa4e7d5ca1b30fb52e420/lib/matplotlib/colors.py).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib fields and methods can be accessed using the

```
matplotlib[:colors][:LogNorm]
```

syntax (i.e. for the corresponding `matplotlib.colors.LogNorm` object).

**UPDATE:** Thank you for your mwe. Based on that example, I managed to make it work like this:

```
PyPlot.pcolor(A, norm=matplotlib[:colors][:LogNorm](vmin=minimum(A), vmax=maximum(A)), cmap="PuBu_r")
```

Comment: Ok, I added an example.

Comment: Many thanks. I updated my answer. Also, just in case you might think I was refusing to answer until you provided a trivial example (which something in my gut tells me might be the case, heheh, I might be wrong!), you might think that was a trivial example, but actually I don't use PyPlot that much so it was helpful to have something to play with, that was guaranteed to both work and be along the lines of what you were looking for. So thanks again for updating your question with one.

Comment: also, just pointing out `minimum` and `maximum` are the equivalent julia methods for finding the minimum and maximum of a collection. (`min` and `max` julia functions also exist, but they do something slightly different).

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a lot!
And I totally understand that it's much easier to find a solution if one has got a simple example of what the problem is :-) Just didn't thought about it immediatly.